# Aptana Studio 3 Full Screen Support

Tags: macos, fullscreen, aptana, osx-lion

Is full screen support for the Mac stand-alone version of Aptana Studio 3 going to be in the works? Mac OS X Lion came out yesterday and I love the full screen apps. I've been trying to find a way to get Aptana to have that same functionality.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add this repo to Aptana :

```
http://github.bandlem.com/
```

And install the fullscreen enabler.

Comment: In windows environment, would not it work?!! I'm getting error while installing this plugin.

Comment: Sorry. This is for OS X Lion fullscreen support, not for windows.

Comment: Hi again, is there any solution for window environment? :(

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is more an Eclipse issue than an Aptana one.  I would suggest posting this as a feature request with Eclipse.